# Why is it possibile to access variables in smarty templates with Prestashop?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

What is the file (or files) that allow me to access all the variables in Smarty templates written in other PHP files?

I can't find a function to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's not a file where you find all the smarty variables. To get one (or more) variables instantiated from other files you have to call a smarty method.

For example, if you have developed a module you have to call:

```
$myvar = $this->context->smarty->GetTemplateVars('myvar');
```

Comment: Thanks you! So, (for example) if you are developing a registration form, you need to call all the variables you need to use? Or have other method to call ALL the variables? In your example, you have called only one variable ora all the template variables? And last thing, ('myvar') is the name or folder where is your controller file? Regards

Comment: @SashaUeChirico Use `{debug}` in a template file and it will open a new window (make sure you don't block popups on that page) which will display all smarty variables that are available on that page.

Comment: Thanks @TheDrot ;)