# Prestashop 1.7 - Get breadcrumb categories in custom module

Tags: product, categories, prestashop-1.7, breadcrumbs

First post on StackOverflow :)

So my issue is that I want to get the current product page category in order to use it in a custom module.

I know that I can get the product categories from my DataBase but it's not what I want.

I thought that I can get the category in the breadcrumb but I try with no success.

Can someone help me please ?

*Edit 1*: I don't want my product category, I already have it. The problem is that my product have more than one category with the same level depth so I need the category that is display in the breadcrumb.

*Edit 2*: I discovered that in the .tpl file of my breadcrumb, I've an array with the categories displayed in the bredcrumb. Did you know how I can get them from my custom module .php file ?

**SOLUTION** : So it's not exactly what I wanted but it gonna make the job. I access to the breadcrumb categories array in my custom module with this line :

```
$this->context->smarty->GetTemplateVars('breadcrumb');
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40260317/18297483

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand what is your problem but i think if you are in php file /module file and you have the id_product that you are working with, then you just

***$p = new Product($id_product);***
and then you can get the category id

> (the direct category parent)

with

***$id_category = $p->id_category_default;***

another solution if you want the full category object might be like this .

***$category = new Category($p->id_category_default,$this->context->language->id);***

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's not what I want.
I don't want my product category, I already have it.
The problem is that my product have more than one category with the same level depth so I need the category that is display in the breadcrumb.

Comment: ( you are welcom) if you want help you must explain more your problem and your context and also share some code

Comment: I'm gonna edit my post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `getCategories()` function in the product class, like this:

```
$p = new Product($id_product);
$categories = $p->getCategories();
```

Then you can loop on each category one-by-one to get any information example 'name'.

Comment: It's what I've use to get my product categories from the DataBase, so for that purpose it work. But it's not what I'm searching for, I'm want something like getBreadcrumbCategories() or something like that. Thanks for your time.